# Updating Listview Images in another thread

Tags: android, multithreading, image, listview

I'm trying to make a custom listview adaptar that can update the imageView in each view asynchronously so that it doesn't slow down.

So far I'm using a vector that storage the bitmaps of the imageviews and in the adapter constructor I'm calling a thread that gets all the bitmaps.
In the getView() method I check if the vector[position] is not null to actually change the imageView bitmap.

here is the code:

```
public class SongAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Song> {
private int resource;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<Song> items;
private Context cntx;
private final Utilities util = new Utilities(); //una per tutte le canzoni
private Bitmap[] covers; //la utilizzo per fare un cashing delle cover

public SongAdapter(Context cntx, int resId, ArrayList<Song> objects)
{
    super(cntx, resId, objects);
    this.cntx = cntx;
    items = objects;
    resource = resId;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(cntx);
    covers = new Bitmap[objects.size()];
    asyncLoadImagesCover(); //lacio un thread per caricare le immagini
}


//carico le immagini nella listview in background
public void asyncLoadImagesCover()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
                covers[i] = util.getAlbumArtFromSong(items.get(i).getPath(), cntx);

            //notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }).start();
}


//cerco di mantenere in memoria l'oggetto in modo da evitare il ricaricamento
private static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView titolo;
    TextView artista;
    ImageView cover;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Funzione che riscrive gli elementi della listview
@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
{
    //recupero l'oggetto canzone
    Song song = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(v == null)
    {
        //creo la view partendo dal layout
        v = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.titolo = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
        holder.artista = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.artistText);
        holder.cover = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.albumImage);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

    //setto i valori a partire dall'holder, in questo modo non devo fare findviewbyid ogni volta
    holder.titolo.setText(song.getTitle());
    holder.artista.setText(song.getArtist());
    if(covers[position] != null)
        holder.cover.setImageBitmap(covers[position]);

    return v;
}
}
```

Anyway this isn't working really well, the 50% of the times the activity crashes and I guess it's because of the new thread.
I searched on the web and found different solutions, but I wanna first understand why my code is crushing. Also, how can I make a thread that updates my listview gui passing v and position in getView?

//////////////////////////////////////////////
EDIT:

For anyone interested, this is what I've done:
I've made a class with two separate object in it that uses one handler to update the UI and an ExecutorService to stack threads that get the image by my function:

```
public class CoverLoader  {

Utilities util = new Utilities();
Context cntx;
ExecutorService executorService;
Handler handler = new Handler(); //si occupa di aggiornare la UI

public CoverLoader(Context cntx)
{
    this.cntx = cntx;
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

public void DisplayImage(ImageView iv, String path)
{
    executorService.submit(new ImageLoader(iv,path));
}


//Separo la parte del caricamento dalla parte di aggiornamento della gui
//questa classe si occupa solo di recuperare la bmp
public class ImageLoader implements Runnable
{

    ImageView iv;
    String path;

    public ImageLoader(ImageView iv, String path)
    {
        this.iv = iv;
        this.path = path;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Bitmap bmp = util.getAlbumArtFromSong(path, iv.getContext());
        handler.post(new BitmapDisplayer(iv,bmp));
    }
}

//Si occupa di aggiornare la UI, richiamata dall'handler a termine del processo di caricamento

class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView iv;

    public BitmapDisplayer(ImageView iv, Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        this.iv = iv;
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

}

Now on the getView():

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
{
    Song song = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(v == null)
    {
        //creo la view partendo dal layout
        v = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.titolo = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
        holder.artista = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.artistText);
        holder.cover = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.albumImage);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

    //setto i valori a partire dall'holder, in questo modo non devo fare findviewbyid ogni volta
    holder.titolo.setText(song.getTitle());
    holder.artista.setText(song.getArtist());
    coverLoader.DisplayImage(holder.cover, song.getPath()); //Richiamo uno stack di thread

    //if(covers[position] != null)
        //holder.cover.setImageBitmap(covers[position]);

    return v;
}
```

So far so good, now I will just find a way (an array maybe?) to save the image that I've already got

Comment: Post a stacktrace if you want to know where it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be doing Threads inside objects bound to Activity context, because it is a short living thing (memory leaks).

You also should not download all images and just these that were requested in getView code (performance).

You should also try to avoid variables accessed by multiple threads (synchronization).

Comment: Got it, I've made too much mistakes. Following what you said I've delegate the job to another class. I'm posting what I've done